# Python Strings and Dictionaries Parsing

Tags: android, python

I have this output from using the readLocation() method from the SL4A API. This is the result. How can I parse this so I only get altitude, longitude, and latitude?

```
    Result(id=2, result={u'network': {u'altitude': 0, u'p
    rovider': u'network', u'longitude': -97.6591116000000
    03, u'time': 1329794430482L, u'latitude': 30.44257223
    3333333, u'speed': 0, u'accuracy': 51}}, error=None)
```

I tried it with this code:

```
   import android, string, time

   droid = android.Android()
   droid.startLocating()
   time.sleep(5)

   res = droid.readLocation()

   print res.result[u'latitude']
```

It returned: 
       KeyError: u'latitude'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Assuming `res` is the name bound to that object](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/AndroidFacadeAPI#API_Browser), `res.result[u'network'][u'altitude']` will get you the altitude. Modify as appropriate for the other keys.

Comment: Oh nvm... I fixed it with print res.result[u'network'][u'latitude'].... Thanks anyways

Comment: Yea and I typed the error... Key Error: u'latitude'... But I fixed it anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As `res.result` obviously consists of nested dicts, `res.result[u'network'][u'latitude']` should do the trick.

Comment: Yea if I figured that out kind of late... Thanks though!!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
res.result[u'network'][u'latitude']
```

since network acts as the key to dictionary containing altitude, longitude & latitude

```
u'network' : { u'altitude': 0, u'provider': u'network',u'longitude': -97.6591116000000    03, u'time': 1329794430482L, u'latitude': 30.442572233333333, u'speed': 0, u'accuracy': 51}
```

Comment: Yea I figured that out kind of late... Thanks though!